# image getting overlaped in table view cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I m parsing a json feed and populating my table view.if my parsed value is "1" and if its for the first four rows of table view cell.i got to make a green checkmark and if its not for the first four rows the checkmark got to be  grey check.if my parsed value is null.i got to make no checkmark.everthng works fine.but if i  scroll my table view .the check mark images gets overlaped.below is the screen shot and the code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//[tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}
NSDictionary *boy=[self.media1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",boy];

if ([str isEqualToString:@"1"]) 
{
    if(indexPath.row==0||indexPath.row==1||indexPath.row==2||indexPath.row==3)
    {
    CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(260, 18, 50, 40);

    UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
    starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tic.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];
    }
    else  
    {
    CGRect starFrame1 = CGRectMake(260, 18, 50, 40);

    UIImageView *starImage1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame1] autorelease];
    starImage1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brrr.png"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage1];

    }


}    

cell.textLabel.text=[story objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code,

```
if ([str isEqualToString:@"1"]) 
{
    if(indexPath.row==0||indexPath.row==1||indexPath.row==2||indexPath.row==3)
    {
        CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(260, 18, 50, 40);

        UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
        starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tic.png"];
        starImage.tag = 1000;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];
    }
    else  
    {
        CGRect starFrame1 = CGRectMake(260, 18, 50, 40);

        UIImageView *starImage1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame1] autorelease];
        starImage1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brrr.png"];
        starImage1.tag = 1000;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage1];

    }

}   
else
{
    UIImageView *starImage = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
    if (starImage) {
        [starImage removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the cell. So, tableView will return used cell once they are not visible.

To avoid this problem, you should right below code.

```
if ([str isEqualToString:@"1"]) 
{
    if(indexPath.row==0||indexPath.row==1||indexPath.row==2||indexPath.row==3)
    {
    CGRect starFrame = CGRectMake(260, 18, 50, 40);

    UIImageView *starImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame] autorelease];
    starImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tic.png"];
    starImage.tag = 1000;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage];
    }
    else  
    {
    CGRect starFrame1 = CGRectMake(260, 18, 50, 40);

    UIImageView *starImage1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:starFrame1] autorelease];
    starImage1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brrr.png"];
    starImage.tag = 1000;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:starImage1];

    }


}  
else
{
UIImageView *starImage1 = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
starImage1.image = nil;
}
```

Comment: :still getting the image.in the else part i m getting a warning "Incompatible pointer types link."

Comment: Cast it with UIImageView *. i.e. (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];